# Visual Studio 2022 C# can't "Find All References" in some cases

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In VS 2022 in a C# project I right-click on a method and select "Find All References"
In some cases it shows no references, but when I put a breakpoint it stops in this method and in the call stack it's a normal call not some reflection magic.
The method in question does reside in a different project than the caller of that method, but they are both in the same solution.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a [mre]?

Comment: When I try to create a minimal example, it finds all references. In our giant solution at work it does not and I can't really share work code even if it was not giant.

Comment: Does the solution target different platforms? Is the project maybe excluded from Build in the solution manager?

Comment: Both projects are included in the build and both of them are .Net 4.8 Class Library. One of them is calling a static method in another.

Comment: But does the solution maybe target different platforms and those projects aren't even considered for this platform? The fact the not even the definition of the symbol itself is found seems to suggest that the IDE ignores your project completely

Comment: All project target the same platform including startup project. Solution does not have a target platform as far as I can tell

Comment: I had to change the dropdown to 'Entire Solution and External Sources' to get references to an internal C# method in the same project/assembly.

Comment: Also, sometimes it still doesn't find what it should, so I change the dropdown to something else, then back to 'Entire Solution and External Sources', and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the `contained by` dropdown is set to `Entire Solution`.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that drop down in the window that pops up after "Find All References" and yes it says Entire Solution  there.

Comment: `View` > `Find Results` > `Find References`.  It opens in the bottom window.  I tried to find settings to change the hover over to solution assemblies, but was unable to find such a setting.

Comment: In the `Object Browser` you can search in specific assemblies or all assemblies.  It is a bit tougher to manage than the find all references window if your type is not easily qualified.  `View` > `Object Browser`

Comment: In the Object Browser if I search for the name of the method it finds all the definitions of the method, but not references to it.

Comment: Oh you are right.  That does only find the definition..

Comment: I believe the original solution is suppose to work, at least that is how the official documentation presents it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-references?view=vs-2022).  `"You can choose to look only in changed documents all the way up to the entire solution."`  I however cannot find the references from other assemblies in vs 2019

Comment: If I make a simple solution with 2 projects and a cross-project call, it finds all references in VS2022 for me. But not for this complex solution at work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution to the problem was:

- close Visual Studio
- delete all `.vs` folders related to the solution and its projects (note that these folders are typically hidden folders)
- re-start Visual Studio